# MYSQL Query that get different values using a condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement

i was looking for something like this:

- forum_reply (id, Text, Data, Post, User)
- forum_post (id, Title, Text, Section, Data, User)

Post, User and Section are foreign keys.

I would show all the posts, of the section that i'm in (i'll use a WHERE Section = '".$_GET['section']."' , i'm working with PHP), order by the data, but:

- If the post hasen't got replys, order THAT post using data of the post
- If the post has more then 0 replys, order THAT post using data of the LAST reply

My final result would be a table that have all the posts rows order by the data that i specified first. Like this:

- POST 1 | 0 Reply | Data of post: 19/12/2014 13:00 -> Take Data of the post
- POST 2 | Reply > 0, Data of the last reply: 19/12/2014 14:00 | Data of post: 19/12/2014 13:15 -> Take Data of the last reply
- ecc..

After that, display all such as:

- POST 2 (19/12/2014 14:00)
- POST 1 (19/12/2014 13:00)

I really can't made that; really need your help! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifnull` function to use date of post, if there are no replies.

```
select *
from forum_post
where Section=@Section
order by ifnull((
    select max(Data)
    from forum_reply
    where Post=forum_post.id
),Data) desc
```

Comment: Thanks very much mate, you've saved my brain!
I've never heard about that function.. Thanks for life.